# how to change password-confirm field value by changing password-new field value in Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

I have to customize **login-update-password.ftl** By default it shows two fields new password and confirm password field. The requirement is to show only the new password field. When I remove confirm password field then it does not work because backend api need both value. Now, I have to hide the confirm password field and change it value by entering data in new password field. I would like to know how this can be done. I attach the code below:

**login-update-password.ftl**

```
<#import "template.ftl" as layout>
<@layout.registrationLayout displayMessage=!messagesPerField.existsError('password','password-confirm'); section>
    <#if section = "header">
        ${msg("updatePasswordTitle")}
    <#elseif section = "form">
        <form id="kc-passwd-update-form" class="${properties.kcFormClass!}" action="${url.loginAction}" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="${username}" autocomplete="username"
                   readonly="readonly" style="display:none;"/>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="current-password" style="display:none;"/>

            <div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!}">
                <div class="${properties.kcLabelWrapperClass!}">
                    <label for="password-new" class="${properties.kcLabelClass!}">${msg("passwordNew")}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="${properties.kcInputWrapperClass!}">
                    <input type="password" id="password-new" name="password-new" class="${properties.kcInputClass!}"
                           autofocus autocomplete="new-password"
                           aria-invalid="<#if messagesPerField.existsError('password','password-confirm')>true</#if>"
                    />

                    <#if messagesPerField.existsError('password')>
                        <span id="input-error-password" class="${properties.kcInputErrorMessageClass!}" aria-live="polite">
                            ${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.get('password'))?no_esc}
                        </span>
                    </#if>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!}">
                <div class="${properties.kcLabelWrapperClass!}">
                    <label for="password-confirm" class="${properties.kcLabelClass!}">${msg("passwordConfirm")}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="${properties.kcInputWrapperClass!}">
                    <input type="password" id="password-confirm" name="password-confirm"
                           class="${properties.kcInputClass!}"
                           autocomplete="new-password"
                           aria-invalid="<#if messagesPerField.existsError('password-confirm')>true</#if>"
                    />

                    <#if messagesPerField.existsError('password-confirm')>
                        <span id="input-error-password-confirm" class="${properties.kcInputErrorMessageClass!}" aria-live="polite">
                            ${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.get('password-confirm'))?no_esc}
                        </span>
                    </#if>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!}">
                <div id="kc-form-options" class="${properties.kcFormOptionsClass!}">
                    <div class="${properties.kcFormOptionsWrapperClass!}">
                        <#if isAppInitiatedAction??>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" id="logout-sessions" name="logout-sessions" value="on" checked> ${msg("logoutOtherSessions")}</label>
                            </div>
                        </#if>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="kc-form-buttons" class="${properties.kcFormButtonsClass!}">
                    <#if isAppInitiatedAction??>
                        <input class="${properties.kcButtonClass!} ${properties.kcButtonPrimaryClass!} ${properties.kcButtonLargeClass!}" type="submit" value="${msg("doSubmit")}" />
                        <button class="${properties.kcButtonClass!} ${properties.kcButtonDefaultClass!} ${properties.kcButtonLargeClass!}" type="submit" name="cancel-aia" value="true" />${msg("doCancel")}</button>
                    <#else>
                        <input class="${properties.kcButtonClass!} ${properties.kcButtonPrimaryClass!} ${properties.kcButtonBlockClass!} ${properties.kcButtonLargeClass!}" type="submit" value="${msg("doSubmit")}" />
                    </#if>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </#if>
</@layout.registrationLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full workaround example for keycloak `20.0.2`.

In your custom theme add the following to `login/register-user-profile.ftl` at the top of the file:

```
<!--
  * we hide the password-confirm field and fill it together with the password field.
-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  function updatePasswordConfirmField(pw) {
    var confirm = document.getElementById('password-confirm');
    confirm.value = pw;
  }
</script>
```

In the same file search for `id="password"` to find the password input field and add the `onchange` attribute:

```
<input type="password" id="password"
  <!-- ... -->
  onchange="updatePasswordConfirmField(this.value)"
/>
```

Still in the same file search for `id="password-confirm"`. From there find the `div` that contains the label and passowrd-confirm field and add `style="display: none;"` to it:

```
<div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!}" style="display: none;">
```

That should fix the UX - but of course we would prefer if keycloak would provide the UX out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This is a crude approach, but you could simply hide the wrapping div of the password confirmation via `style="display: none;"` and add a javascript event handler (see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onblur.asp) that sets the invisible confirmation input to the same value as the password input.

But lets be serious, you should renegotiate the requirement, because the reason why literally everywhere where you have such functionality you have a confirmation input, is that it is very easy to make a type in the password and then the user is locked out.

Comment: It is [commonly agreed](https://www.google.com/search?q=confirm+password+UX) that the better UX is to let the user choose a password without confirmation. For the case of the user having a typo in the password, there is the "forgot password" flow.